# How to include multiple taxes to a product's price?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am using Drupal commerce and have multiple taxes and tax types.

The product price in my site includes 2 types of taxes already added to them (inclusive of both the 2 taxes).

In the product edit page, I get an option to add one of the taxes to be included in the product price.

My doubt is that, how can I select multiple taxes to be included in the product price?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported unfortunately; it would require custom code for both the price field widget and the tax module's saving routine. If that's beyond your capabilities, you'll simply have to reverse calculate the price and enter it, accepting that the rounding may not always work out to nice round product prices like you want.

Comment: Since the 2nd is the easier of the two solutions. Can you suggest me how to do that? the checkout review page's view values are not editable. I tried all the view api hooks. But no luck. Please tell me how to go about the 2nd method. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you'd just have to do that manually before inputting the data into the form. The simplest solution would be a spreadsheet that a merchant can enter a target price into and then you have a couple columns with formulas that reverse the taxes and then give the price that a merchant would actually enter into the price field. Pricing rules would be responsible for for applying the taxes on the front end as the customer shops.